# My resetActive is not working

Tags: javascript

Why does my resetActive call does not work, the background yellow pulls but the resetActive does not. Here is my code:

```
$(document, "#ReloadPage").on('mouseover', function() {
resetActive()
$("#ReloadPage").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Why does my resetActive call does not work?

Comment: What is `resetActive`?

Comment: Put a ; after resetActive() ?

Comment: Plus  Shouldn't that be `$("#ReloadPage").on('mouseover',` You are applying mouseover on the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
#ReloadPage:hover {
    background-color: yellow
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#ReloadPage').on('mouseover', function () {
    resetActive();
});
```